# php array count includes trailing comma

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have an array which I get from an exploded url (using $_GET).
The elements in the url are separated by commas but when I COUNT the elements the result includes the final comma. Eg: `'?list=jonny,sally,bob,'` returns '4' when `'?list=jonny,sally,bob'` returns '3'. I can't avoid the final comma as they are genrated with them automatically but I need to return 3 on both examples. Any ideas please?? Thanks

```
$list = explode(",", $_GET['list']);
$listCount = count($list);
//$listCount =(int)$listCount -1;
//$list[$listCount]=str_replace($list[$listCount],',','');
echo $listCount;
```

NB: the commented out lines are a failed attempt to remove the comma. But $list[$listCount] ,ie the final array element doesn't seem to exist even though it is counted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to trim any extra commas at the start or end of the string, use trim(). If you want it at the end of the string, you can use rtrim().

```
$list = explode(",", $_GET['list']);
```

to

```
$list = explode(",", trim($_GET['list'], ','));
```

Answer (score 2):

[Trim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) any commas first:

```
$strList = rtrim($_GET['list'], ",")
$arrList = explode(",", $strList);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will remove any empty values from your array, so in case you have two commas in a row, it will remove empty values caused by that also.

```
$list = array_filter(explode(",", $_GET['lists']));
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves a more recent problem for me - when a 'count' counts an empty array as 1, instead of 0